# CSS overflow-x & overflow-y properties

Tags: javascript, css

Why setting the css below:

```
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

But inspected by `getComputedStyle()` i got:

```
const {overflowX, overflowY} = getComputedStyle($0);
overflowX === 'auto'
overflowY === 'hidden'
```

Where the `auto` coming from? Why not `visible` as set in css?

Comment: From MDN -> `If overflow-y is hidden, scroll or auto and this property is visible, it will implicitly compute to auto.`   link ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: @Keith that why my border-box is clipped both in x & y . I want the x is visible but y hidden. I'm making a dropdown animation by max-block-size: 0 => max-block-size: 100% => max-block-size: unset

Comment: Are you maybe after -> `overflow-y: clip;` ?    `clip` works like `hidden` but is meant for none scrollable elements..  Only issue of course is Apple.  Recent years Apple has become the new IE6.